# spring rest service resttemplate postForEntity two objects

Tags: java, spring, rest, post

I have a spring rest service and I have a method with two arguments Product and Catalog. The method is

```
public void addProductCatalog(Product product,Catalog catalog) {
        logger.info("******** ******** CLIENT: addProductCatalog");


        ResponseEntity response = rest.postForEntity(
            "http://localhost:8080/rest/addProductCatalog", 
            product, null,catalog);
```

I get an exception when I call this method

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 null
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:707)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:660)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:620)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForEntity(RestTemplate.java:414)
    at com.abc.rest.client.ProductClient.addProductCatalog(ProductClient.java:34)
    at com.abc.InventoryClientApp.run(InventoryClientApp.java:265)
    at com.abc.InventoryClientApp.main(InventoryClientApp.java:24)
```

How can I set two object in postForEntity?

Answer (score 0):

Your method call is incorrect.Create common Pojo comprising both of your objects. Set the content-type as per your need and then call it accordingly.

eg.

```
public class ProductCatalog{
   private Product product;
   private Catalog catalog;

  // getter and setter. 
}
```

and then call it as below:

```
  restTemplate.postForEntity("http://localhost:8080/rest/addProductCatalog", productCatalog, String.class);
```